# How to define my own "Dynamic Web Project" wizard?

Tags: eclipse, wizard

Eclipse Indigo has a "Dynamic Web Project" wizard(File->New ->Other->Web->Dynamic Web Project)

I am not familiar with the plugin development, but I want to create a wizard like "Dynamic Web Project"? Can anyone tell me how to do that? Any tutorial step by step?  more detailed more bettor.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good tutorial on creating wizard in eclipse:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWizards/article.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want "to create  a wizard like "Dynamic Web Project"", the Vogella's tutorial won't help much. And any other [tutorial](http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/dialogs-wizards-2.html) as well. Oh, yes, they will help a bit in understanding the process. And how to make pages. But the example primitive wizards will be of no practical use to you in creating the whole real wizard.

You need to get the "Dynamic Web Project" wizard source from plugins view. It is **very** probable you haven't imported these sources yet. Do it (file-import-plugin development - plugins and fragments ... And set import from repositories!). After that copy the sources of the named project into your project, change its "outer" name, as it shows itself and try if it runs. Make it run.

After that adapt it to your needs by small steps, checking if it continues to run and is doing what you want.

Don't try to understand everything you see there, but try to understand what you are changing.

Feel free to ask - I have managed the same task (with another wizard) just now and I do remember the process yet.

Answer (score 0):

go to the link:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

Comment: I cannot visit the website, any other tutorial in other website?